# roscd: No such package/stack 'navigation' in version kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS kinetic with desktop-full, but I can't find the navigation package with roscd command, but it's OK in version indigo, is it removed or moved to somewhere else in version kinetic?  Hope someone know this problem can help me out, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271437/roscd:-no-such-package/stack-%27navigation%27-in-version-kinetic/) by [Phymin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32008/phymin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to install the package first.  You should be able to run:

`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation`

to install navigation.  Then you need to source the ROS workspace:

`source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`

Once you have both of those, you can then use roscd as you expect:

`roscd navigation`

---

Originally posted by [clalancette](https://answers.ros.org/users/30031/clalancette/) with karma: 256 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phymin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32008/phymin/) on 2017-09-26**:
Thanks for your answer, I think you are right, I will try this tomorrow. But I am a little confused, that I installed the desktop full version, and from the tutorial, the navigation package is included in this version(that's why I ask this question), so   is the tutorial  wrong?

**Comment by [clalancette](https://answers.ros.org/users/30031/clalancette/) on 2017-09-26**:
I just did a clean install of ros-kinetic-desktop-full, and it looks like ros-kinetic-navigation does *not* get installed.  So I think you'll have to install it yourself.

Which tutorial have you been following?  If it is wrong, it is probably a good idea to update it.

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2017-09-26**:
I'm going to assume @Phymin was following the kinetic installation tutorial on the ROS Wiki (http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu):
"Desktop-Full Install: (Recommended) : ROS, rqt, rviz, robot-generic libraries, 2D/3D simulators, **navigation** and 2D/3D percepti..."

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2017-09-26**:
@clalancette is correct. Navigation is not included in ros-kinetic-desktop-full. Unsure if the wiki is incorrect or if it's referring to some other navigation-related packages. I made the same mistake as the OP a week ago, so I agree with that the tutorial should be reworded (though I can't edit).

**Comment by [Phymin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32008/phymin/) on 2017-09-30**:
@josephcoombe @clalancette the tutorial I followed was (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)